# Convert Material-UI DatePicker value to seconds

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

React Material-Ui datepicker currently gives me value like this: **2021-05-26T01:30**
How can I convert it to seconds?

**PS:** I am building a schedule SMS module. So my plan is to convert the selected date into seconds so that I can then use setTimeOut() to send the SMS when the day & time arrives.

Comment: show  your template and tsx file.where are you using datepicker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use setTimeOut, you need to:

1. Compute the difference between the date chosen in the date picker and the current date. This will give you a duration.
2. Convert the duration into **millisecond** as [the delay for setTimeOut is specified in milliseconds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)

To do so the easiest way is probably to use [dayjs](https://day.js.org/docs/en/durations/durations#docsNav), which is a lightweight package to handle Date & Time operations. It works well with react because it is immutable.

Using [dayjs.diff](https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/difference#docsNav) you can compute the duration in milliseconds directly like so :
`const durationInMs = daysj("2021-05-26T01:30").diff(dayjs())`

*note*: By default dayjs [parses datetime in local time](https://day.js.org/docs/en/parse/utc)

## Edit

You can also use the [Native Date Constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#constructor) directl, here's an example from the docs:

```js
// Using built-in methods
let start = new Date()
let end = new Date("2021-05-26T01:30")

let elapsed = end.getTime() - start.getTime() // elapsed time in milliseconds
```